# Двоеточие перед перечислением

Tags: пунктуация

Пишу инструкцию, в подобных случаях ставлю двоеточие, верно ли?

"Поля даты могут быть заполнены двумя различными способами: с помощью специального календаря, либо путём ввода цифр в поле даты с клавиатуры."

Comment: Расставить так знаки препинания можно, но после слова "календаря" не нужна запятая

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, все совершенно правильно. У Вас есть обобщающее слово "способы", а далее идет пояснение, какие именно способы употреблены. Это классический случай постановки двоеточия.

Comment: Спасибо, давненько я не заглядывал в разные справочники, но теперь уверен.